# connect to an authenticating sock5 proxy?

Tags: firefox, proxy, browser, socks5

anyone has successfully connected to authenticating sock5 proxy server?

firefox seems not to support username/password fields when configuring sock5 proxies (see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122752), they have a patch but they didn't pushed it yet to FF, and I'm trying to avoid the need to recompile FF).

chromium uses system proxy settings, which seems not to support sock5 proxy authentication too.

many proxy managers addons seems to be just a backend to the browser proxy settings, and not to add this functionality.

is there any browser that support authenticating sock5 proxy server for linux?

Comment: That bug is 13 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy Toggle for Firefox 57+ works with Socks5 proxy authentication:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/proxy-toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Foxyproxy addon, this should help with your problem.

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: the username and password fields get gray when choosing sock proxy in foxyproxy. (as I mentioned - most browser addones do not implement proxy themselves, but use browser proxy mechanism at backend)